# How do I create an "If, Then" for organizing data?

Tags: r, excel, if-statement, dump

I have an excel sheet that has turned into a large data dump and I need to organize the data. I was hoping to do this in R since I can edit the code to organize multiple items. In essence, I have the data extracted as shown below with each city in its own cell.

> 1 NYC Chicago Detroit LA Miami
> 2 Chicago Sacramento Seattle LA NYC
> 3 Detroit Miami Sacramento NYC Chicago

I need to extract it so that the numbers at the beginning of the row will be organized with the city. It should look like this:

> NYC 1 2 3
> Chicago 1 2 3
> Detroit 1 3
> LA 1 2
> Miami 1 3
> Sacramento 2 3
> Seattle 2

What is the easiest way to do this? I was trying to do an "If, Then" statement, but that does not seem to be working and provides an error.

EDIT: This is a snipit of what the current data looks like. There are 107 rows and 12 columns for reference:

[Current Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkcSb.png)

I am currently using the code

> library(readxl);df1 <- read_excel('C:\Users\Brittney\Desktop\Data_V1.xlsx')
> tidyr::separate_rows(df1, September)

Comment: YOu can use `tidyr::separate_rows(df1, col2)`

Comment: What would be the easiest way to use this function (as in the full code)? I'm having trouble importing the excel sheet, so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong back there. There are also multiple columns.

Comment: to read the excel you can use `library(readxl);df1 <- read_excel('yourfile.xlsx')` once you read the file, replace the `col2` with the name of the column name of your dataset

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to be doing anything different. This is what the current data set looks like (and how ti appears after using that function).

Comment: You meant it is not reading the file?

Comment: It is reading the file, but when I use the tidyr, it does not change the appearance of the imported data.

Comment: what is the column name.  If you could update your post by `edit`ing with `dput(head(yourdata))`, it would be helpful.  AFter doing the transformation, you should update the object with assignment i.e. `df1 <- tidyr::separate_rows(df1, col2)` or to a new object

Comment: I've updated the main post with a picture of the excel data and the code that I am currently running. I want the excel sheet to run all 12 columns (so 12 columns x 107 rows is 1,284 cells). It would take each city (could be in any of the cells) and make those the names of the new columns. The row number that the city came from would then be the new data listed below each column name.

Comment: looks like there are 4 columns instead of the one showed earlier with 2 columns.  In that case, perhaps you need `df1 %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -rn)`

Comment: There are actually 12 columns. I only put 4 to make it look shorter (it would be a very large data set otherwise). I am now getting this error "Error in pivot_longer(., cols = -rn) : could not find function "pivot_longer".

Comment: It is from tidyr

Comment: I get that error when I run df1 %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -rn)